# Handle user-specific data in a SAML authenticated SP

Tags: saml-2.0, simplesamlphp

I am just getting started with SAML. AFAIK, in the authentication step, there is no direct communication between the IdP and the SP and the assertion happens via the browser.

In my applications (which will be the SP), I would like to store some user specific data (stuff like page size, other UI preferences). When the user is deleted from the IdP, I would like to purge this data from my application as well ? Is it possible to get this "event" from the IdP to the SP for such tasks ?

PS - My app is PHP based and I am likely to simplesamlphp.

Thanks,
 ~preetham

Answer (score 2):

There is no support in the [SAML 2.0 spec](http://saml.xml.org/saml-specifications) for having the Identity Provider call out to the Service Provider for events related to user provisioning or deactivation.

However, there is a SAML protocol called `SubjectQuery` and a request called `NameIDMappingRequest` which might serve the purpose if you had a nightly batch job or something that would query users which haven't logged on in x days to see if they still exist on the Idp.

You can find the details on these in the [Profiles Section of the SAML spec](http://docs.oasis-open.org/security/saml/v2.0/saml-profiles-2.0-os.pdf) but I don't know what support (if any) simplesamlphp has for these profiles.

Comment: Thanks, I guess this approach would work for me. Is there anyway the SP can push this data to the IdP, so it gets deleted when the user is deleted from the IdP (I reasonably sure this can't be done, but would like to confirm)